# Wordpress Plugin - change dynamic styles sheet to load under https

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to integrate the foodpress app into my multisite installation. I'm currently have wildcard ssl installed.

This error comes up when I inspect the frontpage of the site in chrome. foodpress_dynamic_styles.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I need to change this section of code so it will load https instead of http so it works properly. (I would ask the developer but the said they no longer support wordpress.)

```
     public function register_fp_dynamic_styles(){
        $opt= $this->fpOpt;

        if(!empty($opt['fp_css_head']) && $opt['fp_css_head'] =='no' || 
     empty($opt['fp_css_head'])){
            if(is_multisite()) {
                $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
                wp_register_style('foodpress_dynamic_styles', $uploads['baseurl'] . '/foodpress_dynamic_styles.css', 'style');
            } else {
                wp_register_style('foodpress_dynamic_styles',
                    FP_URL. '/assets/css/foodpress_dynamic_styles.css', 'style');
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change http to https by finding the code where `FP_URL`  is defined

Or Try below code for quick and dirty method

```
  public function register_fp_dynamic_styles(){
            $opt= $this->fpOpt;

            if(!empty($opt['fp_css_head']) && $opt['fp_css_head'] =='no' || 
         empty($opt['fp_css_head'])){
                if(is_multisite()) {
                    $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
                    wp_register_style('foodpress_dynamic_styles', $uploads['baseurl'] . '/foodpress_dynamic_styles.css', 'style');
                } else {
    $httpsurl = str_replace("http:","https:",FP_URL. '/assets/css/foodpress_dynamic_styles.css';
    wp_register_style('foodpress_dynamic_styles',$httpsurl,'style');
                }
            }
```